# How do i tell if ajax is working?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Currently I am trying to get javascript code working that I didn't write (and I'm only just learning it), after a lot of research and playing around I have guessed that the following code is the problem -

```
$("#btnLogin").click(function(){
        // Check the player login in DB
 //alert("This code is good so far.");
         $.post("fetch.php", {"action": "login", "login" : $("#txtLogin").val()},
            function(data){
              }, "json")            
      })
```

I have edited out the code in function(data) in this example.

If I have the *alert* active the alert button does work - so I deduce that the click(function) works.  But none of the functions ever work :(

Now if I change it to fetch2.php and then make that page have a simple statement of

```
echo "I am here.";
```

then that should appear, am I correct?  Nothing happens when I click the log in button.

What test can I run to make sure this is the code that is causing me grief and (if it is the problem) how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there a semicolon after the bracket?

Comment: What would you like to happen when you click the button? It's a bit hard to say what is wrong when it isn't clear what would constitute "right". To do your "I am here" test you'll need to change the last parameter to `$.post()` from "json" to "text" and then put an `alert(data)` or `console.log(data)` in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your php output as a json array :

```
  $output['alert'] = "I am here.";
  echo json_encode($output);
```

this works if php is > 5.2

and in post :

```
$.post("fetch.php", {"action": "login", "login" : $("#txtLogin").val()},
        function(data){
           if(data){
             alert(data.alert);
           }
          }, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wite some code inside the function, try this bit of code:

```
   $("#btnLogin").click(function(){
        // Check the player login in DB
        //alert("This code is good so far.");
         $.post("fetch.php", {"action": "login", "login" : $("#txtLogin").val()},
            function(data){
               if(data){
                 alert(data);
               }
              }, "json")            
      });
```

according to the echo on your php code, it should alert "I am here.".

Comment: `I am here.` is not valid JSON. If you either made the PHP script output `"I am here."` or did not have jQuery try to parse the [non-]JSON, it would work, however.